# how to use gerrit at best?

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

In our project we use git and gerrit. On each created GCR, job jenkins start executing some checks on the code.
My problem is how to use gerrit. Let me explain better, we currently work this way:
I create a GCR that adds the functionality x to the project, then if I have to apply changes to that functionality, I take the GCR created earlier by doing the cherrypick and push the change. This creates a new pach set at the GCR. In this way, however, by dint of changing that GCR we also create 60 pach sets of the same GCR. Is it correct to work this way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what a "GCR" is or how exacty you are working but I'll try to answer your question...

You must only create a new patchset to an existent Gerrit change if you're fixing issues found by the change reviewers in the review process. You should never push a new patchset to add more more functionality or to change the existing one if the need was not found in the review process. If you're creating 60 patchsets probably it's because you're not just fixing review issues, write? The correct way to work is:

1. Do a change
2. Push the change to review
3. Fix review issues and create a new patchset
4. Repeat step 3 if needed
5. Submit (merge) the change
6. Restart the process

Comment: GCR: gerrit code review. Ok, but if i don't have complete my class and i want push my partial class (to avoid losing changes), how can I do? Can I create: 1 GCR: my class base 2 GCR: my class with fx A 3 GCR: my class with fx B ? after how can I remember all the GCR related to my development?

Comment: I assume you are doing git commit --amend for all you 60 changes. If so you don't really care about the previous 59 changes as only change 60 is important as this is the one that will be merged

Comment: yes use git commit --amend.
Yes, but it's still not clear to me. If I develop a class, on day 1 I create the GCR on gerrit with the first changes, on day 2 I have to add other changes to that class, on day 3 add other changes, etc ... You in this case do the 'amend' to GCR or create different 'N' GCR?
it does not seem right to create 60 new GCR for each change. am I wrong?

Comment: If you want to push to Gerrit only to backup purpuses, you can create a WIP (Work in progress) change. See here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#wip

Comment: my project use version:
Powered by Gerrit Code Review (2.14.16-105-g1fbfa3d565)
and I think this option does not exist
http://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.14.16/intro-user.html

but I can use %draft

Comment: Yes, the WIP feature was created on 2.15 but you can use the "draft".

Comment: I always push in draft. So the way I work is correct? Do I create a GCR in draft and update it N times creating new pachset ?.
The doubt is when we work in parallel, suppose that I develop a GCR 'A', and a colleague of mine develops a GCR 'B'. Suppose that to test both we are dependent on the GCRs of the other. Will the other person have to take my GCR with the cherrypick?

Comment: If you're creating 60 patchsets (we're talking about more than 2 months of work) this is not correct. You need to divide your work in parts and push/review/submit a lot of changes instead of work everything in a big change and use Gerrit just as a backup tool.

Comment: I usually do one or two pachsets every day. The problem is that for but "scrum" methodology we can not merge the code before the end of the "sprint" (2/3 weeks)

Comment: Work in a different branch (let's say sprint1), pushing, reviewing, submitting and, at the end of the sprint, merge the sprint branch to the master.